# Angular js, ngTable data-title has to be set dynamically using model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

In angular js ng table http://plnkr.co/edit/CBcbkc?p=preview, is it possible to replace data-title attributes dynamically using the model values of some other columns?

For example, in

```
 <td sortable="age" data-title="'Age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
```

I want something like  `data-title = {{user.age}}`

Please don't mind if this requirement does not make sense with this example, but in my complex application, I need to set the column title with the some other column value, something like `{{user.age}}, or {{user.name}}`.  In essence I don't want to hard code the titles, rather I want to set some other column values (model value) for its title. I tried different ways to use `{{user.age}}` in replace of `"'Age'"`, but my template compilation is breaking out.

The template sample that I have tried to meet my requirement is:

```
var TemplateSample = '<div class="chartsDiv"> <div class="col">  <p class="graphtitle"> Spend</p> '                         
                     + ' <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table"> <tbody ng-repeat="group in $groups"> <tr class="ng-table-group">  <td colspan="{{$columns.length}}"> '
                     + '  <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows"> <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="'+ngClass12+'"></span> '
                      + ' <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>  </a>  </td> </tr>  <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="user in group.data"> <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+mode+'">  </td> <td sortable="service" data-title="'+service+'">  {{user.service}}  </td> '
                      + '  <td sortable="spend" data-title={{user.month1}}> {{user.percOfTotal1 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + '   <td sortable="spend" data-title={{user.month2}}> {{user.percOfTotal2 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title={{user.month3}}> {{user.percOfTotal3 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month4}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal4 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month5}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal5 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month6}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal6 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month7}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal7 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month8}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal8 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month9}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTotal9 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + ' <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+month+'">  {{user.month10}} </td>  <td sortable="spend" data-title="'+percOfTotal+'"> {{user.percOfTota110 | number:2}} </td>  '
                      + '   </tr> </tbody>  </table> '              
                + '</div> </div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define some function in your controller, like

```
$scope.getTitle = function () {
  return 'Name';
}
```

and then use it in your `data-title` attribute like this:

```
<td sortable="age" data-title="getTitle()">
```

Extending this function, you can add to it some parametr, like this:

```
$scope.getTitle = function (column) {
  switch(column) {
    .../*Some logic*/
  }
}
```

So you could use it for different columns, depending on what you want to do. The main idea is that this function must return `String`.

Also, you should understand that you **can not** to do anything like this:

```
<td sortable="age" data-title="{{user.name}}">
```

and you could not even do anything like this:

```
<td sortable="age" data-title="getTitle(user.name)">
```

because in `ngTable` you `ng-repeats` your data by rows, so users will be repeated, but you have the **unique** title. It's set once and could not be changed.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/XBJLAm?p=preview

### EDIT

@MadasuK: I will repeat: you **can not** to set a `data-title` depending on your `user.name`. You can check it next way:

```
$scope.getTitle = function (param) {
  console.log(param, title);
  return title;
}
```

and in `html`:

```
<td sortable="age" data-title="getTitle(user)">
```

In console you will see that when function `getTitle` is called - `user` is undefined.

By the way, i updated my plunk, you can see now that i added `button` `Change` which will change your title by click. Now `getTitle()` returns local variable `title` and by clicking on the `Change` button this variable is changed, so your title is updated.

Hope, i answered your question.

Comment: Thanks but when I change this <td sortable="age" data-title="getTitle()">, to some thing like <td sortable="age" data-title="getTitle({{user.Name}})">, the plunker is breaking out. Essentially I want to pass model value ({{user.Name}}) to getTitle function. Is there any mistake in my above change?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But please see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/MPgabxFgegKegPYjYGm1?p=preview. I don't want month column to be appeared (as it is unnecessary repetition in each row), instead I want title 'Total1' to be 09-13, title 'Total2' to be 08-13, title 'Total3' to be 05-13, and so on. So I thought of achieving this using something like TemplateSample (I have edited my question with TemplateSample). But from your explanation I understand it is wrong. Is there any way to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

you can add title dynamic: store columns in array item with title attrib.

```
$scope.columns = [
  { title: 'Name', field: 'name', visible: true, filter: { 'name': 'text' } },
  { title: 'Age', field: 'age', visible: true }
];
```

then you can use dynamic table directive:

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with columns" show-filter="false" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{user[col.field]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

you can use this example - [Updated Example 20: Dynamic columns](http://plnkr.co/edit/erbxIh?p=preview)